# Cannot import a package due to [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am running a python service on windows server machine. Python was installed by the administrator for all users. The service is running with an additional account. The additional account runs the python script, but could not import installed packages, like Matplotlib etc. The error message is `[Errno 13] Permission denied 'C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\'`

after this code I am getting the error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The account has the rights to read and write every file and folder on the mentioned path, but still getting the error.

I have tried to install the packages in another path, but still getting the same error.

I am using python 3.12.
Can someone halp?
Thanks!

Comment: You're not showing us the steps you're taking to get to that error message, so it's hard to help. You should nevertheless be using a [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to install your packages in, never into the global system-wide `site-packages`.

Comment: I have tried with `venv`, with addintal folder, with the home folder of the user. Im still getting the mentioned error message, when I run the service

Comment: Please show the actual, full error message and traceback.